# How to get out from grub recovery mode?

Tags: grub2

I have deleted my ubuntu volume in hard disk. Now each time I restart I get in grub recovery mode. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What are you then trying to boot ?

Comment: @SorenA Each time I stat my laptop I got into grub recovery mode.

Comment: do you mean you want to boot back into windows? Maybe telling us what your goal is could help us find a solution.

Comment: @Peetah yes I want to boot again in windows

Comment: EFI or Legacy install?

Comment: @ravery EFI install

Comment: go into the EFI firmware settings, select windows if it allows you to select OS. Then delete /efi/ubunut in the EFI System Partition.

Comment: To remove Ubuntu from your system, you can follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) guide.

Comment: @Peetah -- all those solutions are for Legacy Boot

Answer (score 0):

It goes directly to GRUB because probably it's the first choice on the BIOS boot settings.

Go to your BIOS settings, then boot options. From there, you can move Windows boot to top of the list. After changing the boot order, save and reboot. It should boot directly to Windows now.

(I'd like to give you the exact key combinations and/or screenshots but I don't know your computer model.)

After booting into Windows, you can use this answers to this question to totally remove grub from your computer: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/352112).

Comment: @Ahmetasabanci --  the answer you linked is for Legacy boot not UEFI. FYI -- EFI firmware is not BIOS. BIOS is the Legacy boot system

Comment: I know but depending on the computer itself, this might work too. That answer helped me to solve the same problem on a couple of EFI dual booted Lenovo laptops.